# Do homeomorphisms on a set uniquely determine a topology on the set?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am in the initial stage of a self study in algebraic topolgy and have a question that would appear trivial, except that I cannot come up with a answer:

On a given set, if we are given the quotient set of homeomorphically equivalent classes of elements, does this uniquely determine the topology on the larger set?

In other words, given the quotient set derived from some (unknown) topological equivalence on X, i.e., X/~ , is the implied topology on X unique? and if so, how can one induce it from X/~ ?

Comment: At the very least, you need a topology on $X/\sim$.  Otherwise, we can't distinguish between the two-point space with the discrete topology, and the two-point space with the indiscrete topology.

Comment: Maybe you should add some more conditions.  If $X=\mathbb{R}$, then $X/\sim$ has only one element, and we cannot deduce very much in general about the topology on $X$.

Comment: I think you may be confused about the topological quotient construction. In  the construction of the quotient topology on $X /\sim$, $\sim$ is an arbitrary equivalence relation on $X$ not a topological equivalence (i.e., homeomorphism) on $X$.

Comment: Rob, yes I understand that in a quotient set X/~, the equivalence generally need not be a topological equivalence, but in my problem I am specifically imposing that condition.

Comment: From all the helpful responses, I can see that my question does not make sense in the way I posed it.  How can I "withdraw" my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you take a quotient by any equivalence relation, the map $X\rightarrow X/\sim$ is necessarily not injective (unless $\sim$ is trivial), and hence you lose information.

Whatever topology you choose to put on $X/\sim$, all you can tell is that preimages of open (resp. closed) subsets of $X/\sim$ are open (resp. closed) in $X$.

For example, if $X/\sim$ has the discrete topology, then you know that every fiber (ie, preimage of a point) is both open and closed, but you have control over the topology on $X$ restricted to that fiber. In fact, for any arbitrary choice of topology on every fiber of $X\rightarrow X/\sim$, the "union" of those topologies generates a topology on $X$ which induces the discrete topology on $X/\sim$ and restricts to your chosen topologies on every fiber.

Comment: I am not putting any topology on X/~ .  All I am assuming is: (1) that I know X, (2) that ~ is a topological equivalence relationship and (3) that I have complete knowledge of what is in the equivalence classes of X/~ .

Comment: @user54301 What is your definition of a "topological equivalence relationship"?

Comment: I see where you are going, and you are right - My question does not seem to make sense in the way I posed it b.c. I have defined only one topological space.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in general reconstruct the topology on $X$. For example, take $X=\Bbb N$, let $\tau$ be the discrete topology on $X$, and let $\tau_2$ be the topology generated by the base $\mathscr{B}$ consisting of all sets of the form $\{2n,2n+1\}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation whose equivalence classes are the members of $\mathscr{B}$. Then $X/\!\sim$ is a countable infinite discrete space both when $X$ is endowed with the topology $\tau$ and when $X$ is endowed with the topology $\tau_2$.

Less trivially, define $\sim$ on $\Bbb R$ by $x\sim y$ if and only if $x=y$, or $0\le x,y<1$. Then $\Bbb R/\!\sim$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ itself, which is the quotient of $\Bbb R$ by the identity relation.